# Is this も of concession? いきなり言われても分からない！

Tags: grammar, particle-も

I understand that the meaning is loosely something along the lines of "Asking me so suddenly... I don't know!". 
But I want to understand the function of も here. 
I thought for a time that it is concession e.g.

 
食べてもいいよ,

先生でもたまに勉強する、

高くても買う！

But in this case it doesn't make sense.
Something was asked a question he doesn't know the answer to or doesn't understand, the more time you give him, the probability that he won't know or understand is lowered, thus the highest probability of him not knowing is you ask him いきなり. 
But if we understand the も to be concession then it translates as: "Even if you ask me out of the blue, I do not know/understand!". 
But asking out of the blue is harder than giving him 4 hours to think about it.
 
So I think that "Even if you gave me 4 hours to think about it, I wouldn't have known!" makes more sense for a concession than out of the blue.

So given that line of thought, which function does も serve here? Is it も of emphasizing? Like 三時間も待ってたよ！
Or is it's use as an emphasizer is limited to emphasizing quantities?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is interpretation of concession that strange?

Comment: Yes, very much so.
"Even if you ask me out of the blue, I wouldn't know!"
But wait? Asking you out of the blue would make it harder for you to answer, not easier! 
For example X asks Y a question, Y has a phd in mathematics. Then Y could say "Even if that was a mathematical question, I wouldn't have told you (bearing a grudge for X)" Concession here is possible, because a mathematical question is EASIER for Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is really interesting. I never thought about it that way.

First of all, I'd like to suggest **〜ところで** as the equivalent conjunctive particle:

- いきなり言われた**ところで**わからない (= いきなり言われ**ても**〜)
- 急に来られた**ところで**会えない (= 急に来られ**ても**〜)
- ぜんぶ頼まれた**ところで**できない (= ぜんぶ頼まれ**ても**〜)

I tried to reverse engineer a catch-all translation that is better than `even` or `although`, and I think it's `but`:

- いきなり言われても〜 Tell me out of the blue, but I wouldn't know.
- 急に来られても〜 Come unannounced, but I wouldn't be able to see you.
- ぜんぶ頼まれても〜 Ask me to do everything, but I wouldn't be able to.

Try it out with more examples [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/54391/m0u/) and [here](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E3%81%A7).

---

Side Note: To stretch it a bit, you can maybe even rephrase the other sentences to fit this conceptual mould, too:

- 食べてもいいよ → 食べたところでかまわないよ

  Eat it, but I wouldn't mind.
- 先生でもたまに勉強する → 先生であったところで勉強はする

  Being a teacher, but still study.
- 高くても買う → 高かったところで買いはする

  Be expensive, but I'll still buy.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer!
ところで is a useful way to emphasize that it's concession.
Regarding the side note, I gave them as examples that are clearly concession-related so naturally they fit. 1.Even if you eat it, it's fine 2. Even teachers (or the relevant teacher) studies from time to time. 3. Even if it's expensive, I'll buy it. <br>

Translating the も in this case to `but` certainly works, just like `ては` works as user 4092 mentioned.

Comment: I wonder how does one go about finding out what it really is? I'd bet even some Japanese people wouldn't be able to answer that.
Which makes me ponder philosophically about whether it's necessary to even know if it means `but`, `ては‘ or some expression that works just as fine...

Comment: IMHO I think `ては` is more exclusive than `ても`, and the two aren't interchangeable. 泣いても変わらない (Cry, but it won't change) vs. 泣いては変わらない (It won't change if you cry). You would never say どんなに泣いては変わらない or いくら泣いては変わらない.

Comment: @PsyFish Philosophically, yeah, it isn't like you have a dichotomy and actively choose which one applies. I think it's faster if you broaden the concept of も and treat it as a whole, rather than branch it out into sub-definitions, multiple-choice style. But, what do I know…

Comment: You're right on both points.

Comment: Both answers were possible, and I can't decide on which one.
Chose this in the end, because it was more elaborate.

In case it may interest other people, I've made up a theory of my own of why this is concession.
Perhaps the concession is about a different thing than what initially seems.
いきなり言われてもでわからない, rather than concession on the moment いきなり, perhaps it's concession about something else, like the asker's urgency. So even though it is so pressing as to ask this out of the blue, I don't know. <br> ぜんぶ頼まれてもできない even though it honors me to be tasked with it all, I can't.

Answer (score 2):

How about thinking it's for avoiding ては? Which highlights いきなり, when the speaker would not know it either it's sudden or not.

Comment: Avoiding ては seems plausible in this case, I need to check other cases to see if its there as well.
But what do you mean by "Which highlights いきなり, when..."?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "plausible".
いきなり…ては can imply that if it's not いきなり, it's not necessarily the case, in other words, if it's not いきなり, the speaker could understand it.

Comment: Yep. Just like you say. What I mean by plausible, is that in this example, your suggestion is correct, but I'm not sure if it's a coincidence or not, therefore I'll check a couple more examples where this usage appears, and see if this substitution works.